# Python two list lists shuffle

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I need to get something like this:

```
c = [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]
```

I use this solution:

```
c = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, zip(a, b)))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to get exactly that result, then "shuffle" is not a got word, because it suggests random order. If you want random order, your example is not very lucky. Please specify, which of the two you mean.

Comment: @kratenko: Can you recommend a better term to describe this particular blend?  I first tried 'merge', but my searches here gave answers closer to 'sum'.  Trying 'shuffle' (as in shuffling cards) landed me here, which was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using *List Comprehension*:

```
>>> [x for tup in zip(a, b) for x in tup]
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]
```

The above nested list comprehension is equivalent to following nested for loops (Just in case you get confused):

```
result = []
for tup in zip(a, b):
    for x in tup:
        result.append(x)
```

Comment: Just for clarity, could you please add the nested for loops to explain how this actually works. I'm sure there are quite a few people saying __wait... what?__ when they first see this :)

Comment: @Kimvais. Do you mean the general for loops equivalent of this?

Comment: yes. Newbies will need to squint really hard to figure out which one is the inner and which one is the outer for loop and what goes in to `tup` :)

Answer (score 6):

Using `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain, izip
interweaved = list(chain.from_iterable(izip(a, b)))
# [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Also viable:

```
list(sum(zip(a, b), ()))
```

Comment: Nope, about the same, a bit faster even on my machine. Comprehension wins on larger lists.